# Killing other user processes

Tags: shell-script, users, kill, signals

There are certain user environments in which we have to login during certain performance testing and and kill all the process running in that environment.

The environment names are like `rswrk01`, … up to `rswrk98`.
and this is how we login.

```
sudo su - rswrk96
```

It doesn't prompt for any password and straightaway logs in.

Is it possible to automate a script for killing all the running processes in all the environments, instead of logging in manually and killing the processes?

I am not the root user by the way.

```
$ uname -a
HP-UX rcihp145 B.11.23 U 9000/800 3683851961 unlimited-user license
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So `rswrk01` and co are users. An occasionally-useful of [`kill`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/kill.html) is that if you pass -1 as the PID, the signal is sent to all processes that the signal sender has permission to send signals to. In other words, for a non-root user, `kill -$sig -1` sends the signal to all processes running as that user. This includes the killer, but the delivery is atomic, so all concerned processes do get a signal.

Now all you have to do is put this in a loop, and you're done. Since formatting numbers with leading zeroes is a bit of a pain, a not very nice-looking but convenient trick is to put a leading `1` (i.e. count from 101 to 198 rather than 1 to 98) and strip that off.

```
i=101
while [ $i -le 98 ]; do
  sudo su - rswrk${i#1} kill -KILL -1
  i=$((i+1))
done
```

Or in ksh:

```
for ((i=101; i<=198; i++)); do
  sudo su - rswrk${i#1} kill -KILL -1
done
```

Or in bash or zsh:

```
for i in {01..98}; do
  sudo su - rswrk$i kill -KILL -1
done
```

Comment: +1 very good answer indeed, I like it and I hope it works when i test it

Answer (score 6):

`sudo -u rswrk96 -i killall ...` should be the same as doing `su - rswrk96` and then `killall ...`.

What's left is generating the sequence 00-96. This should work:

```
for i in $(seq -w 00 96); do sudo -u rswrk$i -i killall ...; done
```

---

Now that I think of it, you could probably just do

```
for i in $(seq -w 00 96); do sudo killall -u rswrk$i; done
```

Don't need to login.

Comment: your answer seems reasonable, but there is no pkill in hp unix I gave `which pkill` and nothing returned

Comment: by the way, what is that -i used before pkill does

Comment: any other ideas people

Comment: 1. OK, I replaced it with `killall`. See `man killall` to read what options you can put there (an idea: `killall -u rswrk$i` would kill all processes of that user). 2. The `-i` argument to `sudo` is the same as the `-` argument to `su`: it runs the user's login scripts, which create its environment.

Comment: `$ sudo -u rswrk96
usage: sudo -V | -h | -L | -l | -v | -k | -K | [-H] [-S] [-b]
            [-p prompt] [-u username/#uid] -s | <command>`  this is what i get when i give sudo -u instead of sudo su - donno why

Comment: What operating system are you using? Use `-s` instead of `-i`. Or try the other variant (without sudo).

Comment: No i just tried to login using `sudo -u rswrk96` thinking whether it will work or not. I cant kill any proceeses right now just wanted to test it

Answer (score 1):

`kill -9 -1` will simply revoke all the processes running on behalf of the command executing user, even the shells. You can try this with sudo to kill other user's processes.
`sudo -u user1 kill -9 -1`

Or just simply use `-u` flag to `pkill` command.